# How to avoid using `$parent.$parent.$parent` in nested scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

#### How can I know the Parent controller name in controller chain of Angular?

I'm new to Angular so I have one basic question.

Suppose, In Angular, I have a controller's chain like below.

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
  ... something in the parent element
  <div ng-controller="childController">
     ... something in the child element
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to write the code in the child element so that I can know the parent controller name in the output (In this case output should be 'parentController')?

I need this because I have a too big project and want to know the parent of each controller because someone has wrote the code like

```
googleOAuth= $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.status.googleOAuth
```

and I'm not able to understand so want to know the parent of each $scope.

Comment: The use of `$parent` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. You have inherited some messy code.

Comment: Child scopes can be created not just by `ng-controller` but other directives such as `ng-if`, `ng-repeat`, etc. For more information, see [AngularJS Wiki - Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Dev-Guide%3A-Understanding-Scopes). New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes

Answer (score 2):

On approach is to use "controller as" syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="parentController as top">
     <!-- ... something in the parent element -->
  <div ng-controller="childController">
     <!-- ... something in the child element -->
     {{top.status.googleOAuth}}
  </div>
</div>
```

This requires the controller be written using the `this` context instead of `$scope`.

---

Another approach is to use a property of an object in the parent scope:

```
app.controller("parentController", function($scope) {
    $scope.top = {status: {} };
    $scope.top.status.googleOAuth = value;
});
```

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
     <!-- ... something in the parent element -->
  <div ng-controller="childController">
     <!-- ... something in the child element -->
     {{top.status.googleOAuth}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Because scopes use prototypical inheritance, the `top` property is available to child scopes.

See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Hierarchies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies).

Answer (score 1):

As georgeawg said, using $parent is not optimal because it relies on a constant number of scopes.

Instead, you could write a service to deal with your googleOAuth.
The service can then be injected in each controller and will function as a single source of truth because services are singletons in AngularJS.

e.g. something like this

```
angular.module('appModule', [])
    .factory('googleOAuthService', [function() {
        var googleOAuth = {
            // your googleOAuth stuff here
        };

        return {
            get: get,
            set: set,
            stuff: stuff
        }

        function get () {
            return googleOAuth;
        }

        function set (newGoogleOAuth) {
            googleOAuth = newGoogleOAuth;
        }

        function stuff () {
            // Do stuff to googleOAuth
        }
    }])
    .controller('parentController', ['googleOAuthService', function(googleOAuthService) {
        googleOAuthService.stuff();
    }])
    .controller('childController', ['googleOAuthService', function(googleOAuthService) {
        googleOAuthService.stuff();
    }]);
```

For more info, see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services